# Can't update state of parent from deeply nested children in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, svg, state

I'm trying to construct some SVG of a tree (a json-object) recursively using react components.
Every node (a tree's node) component returns other nodes (and edges) until there are no more child-nodes. The tree renders perfectly on my screen.

Now I want to count all the leafe-nodes using a function which I pass down via props to all the nodes. When a node got no child-nodes, it calls the function in its constructor. With this function I want to increase this.state.countLeafs of my main component using this.setState. The function got called as often as there are leafe nodes in my tree (I'm checking it with console.log). For every leaf node the function got called, but my state does not update.

my main component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SpecNode from './graphicTreeComponents/SpecNode.js';

class GraphicController extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.incLeafs = this.incLeafs.bind(this);
        
        this.state = ({
            u: {key: "0", x: 100, y: 0, k: 
                    [
                    {key: "1", x: 40, y: 100, k: null},
                    {key: "2", x: 160, y: 100, k: null}
                    ]
                },
            countLeafs: 0
        })
    }
    incLeafs(){
        console.log("leafs++");
        this.setState({countLeafs: this.state.countLeafs + 1});
        console.log(this.state.countLeafs);
    }
    render(props){
        return (
            <div className="GraphicController">
                <SpecNode {...this.state.u} incLeafs={this.incLeafs}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default GraphicController;
```

and my node component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Edge from './Edge.js';
import SpecNode2 from './SpecNode.js';

class SpecNode extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        if(!this.props.k){
            this.props.incLeafs();
        }
    }

    render(props){
        return(
            <svg>
                {this.props.k ? 
                    this.props.k.map(e =>
                        <svg>
                            <Edge x1={this.props.x} y1={this.props.y} x2={e.x} y2={e.y} />
                            <SpecNode2 {...e} incLeafs={this.props.incLeafs}/>
                            <circle cx={e.x} cy={e.y} r={5} fill={"lightgrey"} />
                            <text fontSize={7} x={e.x-2} y={e.y+3} fill="black">{e.key}</text>
                        </svg>
                    ) 
                    :
                    null
                }
            </svg>
        );
    }
}
export default SpecNode;
```

Is there anything fundamental I miss?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the leafCount is not updating? setState is asynchronous, but it takes a callback. Your console.log might be happening before your state is updated. You should try something like...

```
incLeafs(){
    console.log("leafs++");
    this.setState({countLeafs: this.state.countLeafs + 1}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.countLeafs);
    });   
}
```

In your main component, you don't need the parentheses when initializing state.

```
this.state = {
        u: {key: "0", x: 100, y: 0, k: 
                [
                {key: "1", x: 40, y: 100, k: null},
                {key: "2", x: 160, y: 100, k: null}
                ]
            },
        countLeafs: 0
    }
```

You could also try moving your function call to componentDidMount within the SpecNode component

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
componentDidMount() {
    if(!this.props.k){
        this.props.incLeafs();
    }
}
```

Comment: even with bigger trees it just calls the incLeafs function once

Comment: Another problem is the way you declare this.state in your parent component. It shouldn't have the parentheses.

Comment: Edited my answer to include the suggestion that you call the function in componentDidMount rather than inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `this.incLeafs` is not bound to the parent component.  Because of that, when it runs, `this` doesn't mean the `GraphicController` when the child node calls the method.

Either

A) change the way you've written the method on the parent class into an arrow function, like this: `incLeafs = () => {...};`

B) manually bind the method method at some point with something like `this.incLeafsHandler = this.incLeafs.bind(this)` and then pass `this.incLeafsHandler` as the incLeaf callback to SpecNode. ((I strongly don't like this solution, but that's just my preference.))

C), pass it down as an arrow function in the props (as `<SpecNode ... incLeafs={() => this.incLeafs()} />`)

Arrow functions always retain `this` as whatever it was when the arrow functions were declared. ( Options A and C )

Normal functions will change `this` based on where they're getting called, unless you use a bound copy of the original method. ( Option B )

Comment: I checked out option A but it didn't work. Then I replaced `this.state.countLeafes + 1` with `this.state.countLeafs++` and now it works. Is it ok to do it like this?

Comment: Aha!  That was the problem... When you call `x++`, x is incremented BUT if you say `x = 0; y = x++;` then you end up with y being 0 and x being 1.  This is because `x++` increments x and RETURNS the original value that x was before it was incremented.  So before you were always setting state to the value it already was, and now you are setting state to that value + 1.  This is why `countLeafs + 1` works